# Remotely check for changes since a revision date/time without pull

Tags: git

I am looking for a way to check a `git remote` for changes since my last fetch.

I understand that git works on the principal of having the fetch a remote see changes, and yet I know of many continuous integration tools such as "TeamCity" that are able to "ping" a remote for changes.

I would like to know how build agents etc do these checks so that I can write my own tool for notifying people of changes to a repo.

what git command would you use to check for changes on a `git remote`?

would `git ls-remote .` suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build agents do it generally by having the server ping them on changes and that is accomplished with a `post-receive` hook that sends a HTTP POST with the new commit SHA. I don't see a reason to check the remote without fetching.

`git ls-remote` would get you the commit SHA's which you can obviously compare to your local ones but that wouldn't get you any info about how many commits are done.

Comment: Great info!

I would assume that a build agent Ping service its important to know "something has changed" rather than how many changes or the details. Especially if the PING is simply used to kick off CI, or kick off a second process to pull the commits and then have the info. Thoughts?

Comment: Totally true you will end up fetching them to build it anyways. But from what i said above the post-receive hook way is way cleaner then ls-remote every few hrs

Comment: I think the big problem with webhooks is that you assume you have access to the remote repo. I am writing a service to check *someone elses* repo, and if it is updated, do a shallow clone.

Comment: Well ls-remote is the way i would go then. As I really don't need to know what has changed in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing they do the "ping" by doing a `git fetch` and seeing what refs change. The `post-update` hook can be used to check this.

Another way to see if branch `foo` on remote `bar` has changed is to do a `git fetch bar foo`, which fetches the branch into `FETCH_HEAD`, and then running e.g. a `git log bar/foo..FETCH_HEAD` to compare your old version of `foo` with the just-fetched one.

One last comment: you can use `git ls-remote` to see if a remote branch has been updated after you last saw it, but to access commit metadata (date) you'll have to fetch.

Comment: Yeah they don't fetch - TeamCity and Bamboo check every 90 seconds and dont keep your repo local. It would be too costly to fetch. They must do `git ls-remote` and just check if the changeset is different to the last one they got?

Comment: OTOH [buildbot](http://buildbot.net/buildbot/docs/current/manual/cfg-changesources.html#chsrc-GitPoller) uses fetching to poll.